# Connection to Oracle database since upgrade dbplyr not working

Tags: r, oracle, dplyr, odbc, dbplyr

I am trying to connect to an Oracle database with dplyr and dbplyr backend. However since the upgrade of dbplyr to version 2.0.0 it no longer works and getting the following error.

```
x <- tbl(con, in_schema("dm", "DM_CLT_POS_OVL_LIAB_HEDGE"))
```

> Error in .oci.GetQuery(conn, statement, data = data, prefetch = prefetch,  :
> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

In the previous version of dbplyr I could make it work with the redirection functions ( see below) but they have been removed with the upgrade.

```
#below are required to make the translation done by dbplyr to SQL produce working Oracle 
SQLsql_translate_env.OraConnection <- dbplyr:::sql_translate_env.Oracle
sql_select.OraConnection <- dbplyr:::sql_select.Oracle
sql_subquery.OraConnection <- dbplyr:::sql_subquery.Oracle
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Came across the same issue using `RJDBC` package instead of an `ODBC` driver based approach and found the solution for it on the [github page of `dbplyr`](https://github.com/tidyverse/dbplyr/issues/529).

I'm not sure, whether it works and cannot try it myself but you might try to replace your assignments with these here:

```
SQLsql_translate_env.OraConnection <- dbplyr:::sql_translation.Oracle
sql_select.OraConnection <- dbplyr:::sql_query_select.Oracle
sql_subquery.OraConnection <- dbplyr:::sql_query_wrap.Oracle
```